# AWS ECS Fargate disable Health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a container running within AWS ECS using Fargate.

I register it with the Terraform below and add the hostname to the service discovery. I see it adds it into route53 and then it removes it, I'm assuming this is due to it failing a health check.

It fails 
with this below error when I start the container:

> company/cmd createServer net.Listen company.qcap.prod:50031 listen tcp:
>   lookup company.qcap.prod on 10.0.0.2:53: no such host

My service can't listen on the address until the host is registered within Route53 but then my Route53 removes the DNS entry if it fails a health check.

Is there a way to tell the task to wait until that entry is added and then do the health check?

Below is my Terraform for the service

```
data "template_file" "company" {
  template = file("./templates/ecs/company.json.tpl")

  vars = {
    app_port = 50010
    fargate_cpu = var.fargate_cpu
    fargate_memory = var.fargate_memory
    aws_region = var.region
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "company" {
  family = "company-app-task"
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = [
    "FARGATE"]
  cpu = var.fargate_cpu
  memory = var.fargate_memory
  container_definitions = data.template_file.company.rendered
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "company-service" {
  name = "company-service"
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.company.id
  desired_count = var.app_count
  launch_type = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [
      aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id
    ]
    subnets = module.vpc.private_subnets
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  service_registries {
    container_name = "company"
    registry_arn = aws_service_discovery_service.company.arn
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ecs_task_execution_role
  ]
}

resource "aws_service_discovery_service" "company" {
  name = "company"

  dns_config {
    namespace_id = aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace.qcap_prod_sd.id
    routing_policy = "MULTIVALUE"
    dns_records {
      ttl = 10
      type = "A"
    }
  }

  health_check_custom_config {
    failure_threshold = 10
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a DNS name for the listen address. That offers no benefit. Use `0.0.0.0` to listen on all available interfaces.

Comment: How will that work with separate ECS tasks within Fargate trying to communicate with eachother?

Comment: It won't affect it whatsoever. It's just use to determine which local network interface to bind to.

Comment: So if i have a separate service that wants to talk to my service that is listening on 0.0.0.0:5010 they can just do dial(0.0.0.0:5010)?

Comment: No, they would dial the DNS name. The external endpoint is not the same thing as the local interfaces a service binds to. Your ECS configuration looks fine, your app configuration is what's likely wrong.